# Making Dynamic SQL Queries in SAS Proc Sql

Tags: sql, sas

Here's an edit that reflects some progress made:

I have the following function that works:

```
proc fcmp outlib=mydir;
 function sqlWhere(interval $, myDate $) $;
 ...
 return("id");
 endsub;
quit;
```

This is tested and works fine.  So I tried:

```
%macro sqlWhere(interval, myDate);
  &interval.("year") AS t
  &myDate.("someDateField") AS tt
%mend;
proc sql;
  CREATE TABLE test AS (
    SELECT %sqlWhere(t, tt)
    FROM myTable);
quit;
```

The top part runs fine when I run selection. However, the proc sql blows up and says I'm missing a comma. I'm confused because the function is returning " id " in other tests which should make the code work.  The error says there is a missing comma on the "tt" part...

I'm attempting to make a dynamic query in SAS. I'm having a couple of issues and I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible. Also, sorry for deleting a prior question; I wanted to give a better explanation.

Say I have this code:

```
proc sql;
SELECT 
  YEAR(myDate) AS yr, 
  MONTH(myDate) AS mo,
  id
FROM
  myTable;
run;
```

I'm trying to make it conditional. This gives two problems. First, I can't get the basic syntax to work. Second, I can't get my custom function to create the proper string.

I want something like this:

```
%let a = sqlDate("month");
proc sql;
SELECT
  &a
FROM
  myTable;
run;
```

This structure doesn't work, even when I forgo the function and just enter

```
%let a = "YEAR(myDate) AS yr, MONTH(myMonth) AS mo, id";
```

Is something like this possible?

My second issue is how to construct the function itself, but I want to confirm I can even do something like this first. I'm basically putting an indicator in a master program that is either "day", "week", "month" or "year" and then telling the program to query SQL in a given way. Can I pass whole strings someway? Is it possible to build strings based on inputs in this manner?

Comment: You did indeed overlook a comma in the macro at the end of this line: &interval.("year") AS t In a sql select, you need to separate the different things you select with a comma, but there is none between the part for variable t and the part for variable tt. (putting on different lines does not free you from having to place comma's. ;))

Comment: I found this extremely helpful explanation of macro variables and macros: [“SAS® Macros Are Just Text Substitution!” ... ARRRRGGGHHH!!!](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/142-2010.pdf)

Comment: Hey guys, I just can't get it working with the function.  This is all good info, but I'm going to make a new question that is more specific and see if I can narrow down what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first issue is explained by a misunderstanding of SAS macro.
When you put this:

```
%let a = "YEAR(myDate) AS yr, MONTH(myMonth) AS mo, id";
```

SAS will put into your query:

```
"YEAR(myDate) AS yr, MONTH(myMonth) AS mo, id"
```

I.e.: it will keep the quotes. If you want to 'hide' things like functions away when putting it in a SAS macro variable, you have to use the %str() function instead of " or '.
So if you would write:

```
%str(YEAR(myDate) AS yr, MONTH(myMonth) AS mo, id);
```

You would have something that works.

To answer your second question: that is certainly possible. But keep something very important in mind: any macro function, macro variable defintion or call to a macro variable that is in open code, is interpreted and replaced before your SAS code runs.
If you have a macro variable/function that depends on results from a SAS data step or proc, you need to encapsulate it in a macro function: everything in it is only interpreted and replaced during runtime.

*EDIT*
To answer your comment: it is mainly general advice i'm passing along because you seem unfamiliar with SAS Macro. In some cases, you can get weird results where it looks like your macro variable was not set/changed and if you're not aware of it, it can be frustrating. (and we all ran into it for a first time ;))

In your specific case, if we assume you have made an sqldate macro that returns the appropriate select part, you're probably best off putting it immediately into the query. e.g.:

```
%macro sqldate(period);
    &period.(mydate) as period
%mend;
/*note no semicolon, since a macro function is basically the same as saying: resolve this piece of macro code and add the result directly to my written code.*/

proc sql;
    select %sqldate(month)
    from mytable;
quit;
/*also note: you end proc sql with a quit statement instead of run*/
```

Comment: Ok, I follow what you say on %STR but I'm a little confused about the macro function encapsulation.  In my example, assuming sqlDate("Month") returns the string I want, how do I encapsulate that value so the query can interpret it at runtime?

Comment: I figured out how to get the function to work great, just need to integrate it into the query and I'm seeing the problems you are referencing! :)

Comment: Hi @JeffreyKramer i updated my response in an attempt to answer your additional comments. If not clear yet or if you end up with unexpected results, i propose to add your new attempt as an edit to your post.